# realm-java data lost when restarting application

Tags: android, restart, realm

I'm using realm-android 0.74.0 with android 4.4.2
I create an instance of realm, populate it with objects and commit the transaction.
My objects are saved fine. I can load them and manipulate them.
But each time i restart my application the data is **lost**

Has anyone run into the same problem ?

Comment: By saved you mean actually persist them to storage where you can see them in the file folders?

Comment: Tim from Realm here. We haven’t seen any reports of data loss with Realm. We definitely want to help if something is wrong, but we can’t do that without some more details about your app. User geisshirt [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27041512/3838010) is also a Realm employee and he can help if you can share some code we can look at either here, or if you prefer, privately at help@realm.io.

Answer (score 2):

Christian from Realm here.

Your login button onClick handler have this method:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        // Delete database
        Realm.deleteRealmFile(getActivity());
        ...
    }
});
```

This deletes the default realm file and by that your data. Where you trying to accomplish something else by this line?

Comment: Yes i delete the realm file here but my TasksFragment is runing a service that recreate an instance of realm and feed it. Because i want to "reinit" the realm file when another user log in

Comment: But the current code also deletes the Realm file when the same user logs in, effectively deleting all the old data. If you want to separate user data you can instead use Realm.getInstance(context, "username") to get a separate Realm file for each user.

Comment: Yep it's true. But i keep it that way for the time being as it can be also used to refresh all the data. My login procedure work a bit like a clear cache mechanism

Comment: I probably shouldn't use it that way and only clear tasks RealmObjects with something like result.clear(); ?

Comment: Deleting the file is fine. But I am uncertain about your original problem. If it is by design that you delete all user data when logging in, what data is being lost?

Comment: It's a bit weird that why i asked for help. When i feed my realm file without calling deleteRealmFile first the data is persisted even if the app restat. But if i call deleteRealmFile on application start for example my list of tasks i empty when i restart

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call Realm.deleteRealmFile(getActivity())?

Comment: The gridViewExample does the same thing : deleteRealmFile then feed the realm instance with cities. And i'm sure that the data is kept. I must be doing something wrong somewhere. Anyway it's not a realm issue. I will look into it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the following

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.connect);
    final EditText username = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            // Call user login service
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(getString(R.string.app_url_base))
                    .build();

            AppService service = restAdapter.create(AppService.class);

            service.login(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void success(User user, Response response) {

                    if (user.isSuccess()) {
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Const.PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Logged username: " + user.getUsername());
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_username), user.getUsername());
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_password), user.getPassword());
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_lastname), user.getLastname());
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_firstname), user.getFirstname());
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_md5), user.getMd5());
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.success_login), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Delete database
                        Realm.deleteRealmFile(getActivity());

                        // Delete log file
                        File logFile = new File(Const.LOG_FILE);
                        if (logFile.exists()) logFile.delete();

                        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.container, TasksFragment.newInstance(2, 0))
                                .commit();

                        //((MainActivity) getActivity()).openDrawer();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_login), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "retrofitError:" + retrofitError.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_login), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

but by moving 
    Realm.deleteRealmFile(getActivity());
before the retrofit call it's seems to work ok

The TasksFragment is running a Service which persist the RealmObjects

Thanks for your help